# Magento : show new products on home page

Tags: magento

I am working on my first Magento project. I want to display new products to the home page

I have researched and added this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="3" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

And it worked until I added products from a category to same home page. Code is

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/bestlist.phtml"}}
```

Now it shows products from category but not new products. I have disabled cache and also flushed all the existing cache.
I have tried and checked many ways but coulnt figure it out.

Can some body help me with a solution for this please?

PS: I am using latest version of magento 1.7.X

Thanks in advance,
Kiran

Comment: I think you need to refresh the indexes after new products are added to the category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, go to “CMS” > “Pages” > select “Home Page” (URL Key: home).
Click on “Design”
Paste the following XML update into the field provided:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
<action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action> 
</block>
</reference>
```

If you would like to increase/decrease the amount of products per column, please change

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
```

to

```
 <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
```

Also if you would like to limit the amount of products shown, change

```
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action>
```

to

```
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>3</count></action>
```

Please note: For the products to show on the homepage you MUST ensure you have marked the products as new by setting “Set Product as New from Date” and “Set Product as New to Date” options in the “General” tab.

Answer (score 4):

First, go to “CMS” > “Pages” > select “Home Page” (URL Key: home). Click on “Content” Paste the following Code

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" show_pager="1" products_per_page="50" products_count="50" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

Its working for me;
also we can set product limit on single page.

Answer (score -2):

The code you used is for categories only. If you want to add a new module like new products in your magneto store , you have to search a Magento extension from http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user1389568 Are you saying both blocks of codes does same thing? pulling products from a category?. I can see new products ( marked as new using 'set new from' ) for a while before I added code to show products from a category. I will try using that magento connect and post reply here.