# Get latest or new products on home page in magento with layout update

Tags: magento

I create new theme in Magento and want to show latest or new products on home page with pagination and number of show product. I copied catalog/product/list.phtml from it's cored file to my template so that i can customize it.

Below is code in layout update in homepage:

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
      <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
      <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
      <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/></block>
      <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

It work well with is code, but only with category I set in layout update.

```
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
```

What I want is get all latest or new product from all category.

Question: how can I get latest or new products with layout update with all category or multiple category?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento : show new products on home page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037967/magento-show-new-products-on-home-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Here you can ‘Set Product as New from Date’ and ‘Set Product as New to Date’ options in the ‘General’ product information page in the admin tool will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Open Magento admin panel

Go to `CMS > Pages > Home page`

Switch to the content tab

Insert the following code:

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6"  products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new"  alias="product_homepage"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Where:

`column_count="6"` – number of the product columns

`products_count="12"` – number of the displayed products

Comment: if you use this only show new products in this case 12. i want is product list with pagination and number of show products.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is by using Magento Widget.

From your CMS homepage, go to content and clic on the second item in wysiwyg menu: *Insert widget*.

Then, a popin appear, choose in *Widget Type*: *Catalog New Products List*.

Clic on *Insert widget* and it's done.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use on my homepage:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="11" num_products="16" template="catalog/random.phtml"}}
```

I use this on the homepage to show items from that category directly. This way I dont have duplicate content issues and the user links directly into the category.

You can see an example on our website [www.SaveTheMage.com](http://www.SaveTheMage.com)

Comment: you can use this code, but it get product only from category_id=11 that you set for it. I want to get new products from all category