# new products on homepage magento - fatal error

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm trying to use the commonly suggested block to my magento homepage that would allow me to display new products.

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

For some reason, I'm getting the following error

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /app/code/local/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php on line 94

Anyone have any clue what this could be about?

Comment: problem is with your block code. So kindly post the code of your block

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6"  products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new"  alias="product_homepage"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Use

```
template="catalog/product/list.phtml
```

instead of

```
template="catalog/product/new.phtml
```

Where:

column_count="6" – number of the product columns

products_count="12" – number of the displayed products

reference : [Get latest or new products on home page in magento with layout update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583578/get-latest-or-new-products-on-home-page-in-magento-with-layout-update)

Comment: I'd actually tried that before I posted and got the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /home/feldbcom/public_html/app/design/frontend/feldheim/blank/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 37